# how to install playerctl in Mac

Tags: python-3.x, macos

How can i install "playerctl" in macos?
I want to use `os.system("playerctl play")`.
I get error

> sh: playerctl: command not found

if not what alternate can I use?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

`playerctl` uses MPRIS, which is a D-Bus interface and D-Bus is only available for Linux.

For a macOS alternative, see: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229542/is-it-possible-to-invoke-play-button-using-terminal

Comment: from the link above I can play from terminal using command `osascript -e 'tell application "Spotify" to play'` . but how can I run this within python script?

Comment: You can use `os.system()` to run any Terminal commands or use `applescript` package: https://pypi.org/project/applescript/